# Are channels in hyperledger fabric independent private blockchains?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to understand the fabric architecture. If channels are independent blockchains then how is it connected to other blockchains in different channels in the same network? Also, can members of the same networks see the blockchain of a different channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to first question: They are not connected. The different channel runs on the same network i.e. they may share peers/orgs/orderers, but that's it.

Second, yes, they can, if the members have subscribed to both the channels.

Comment: are these channels dynamically created e.g. if a new org has joined the network than network creates a new channel for it ?

Comment: Channel creation and org joining are independent processes. a newly joined org can subscribe to an existing and long-running channel.